# Query to separate words in a sentence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need query to separate words from a sentence in a table

For example 
 In my table I have a column (place)..

Place contains value like

```
INDIA | Tamilnadu |chennai 
India |andhra |hyderabad
```

So I need a query to put the three things into different column separated by delimiter

Comment: What database are you using?  Do all the place names have the same structure, with three elements?

Comment: Thank u for ur Response ..but am using Sql Server ,so its not supporting and also i will always have the same structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve same by using this method also.

```
declare @String1 varchar(200);
set @String1 = 'www|eee|rrr';

select PARSENAME(REPLACE(@String1,'|','.'),3) 'First_Place'

select PARSENAME(REPLACE(@String1,'|','.'),2) 'Second_Place'

select PARSENAME(REPLACE(@String1,'|','.'),1) 'Third_Place'
```

Comment: Thank u Hardik..its working..But i need to update a table with 10000 rows.wt s d best way .can i go for cursor?

Comment: @Yes You can go with the cursor but CTE will be the best option

Comment: @KarthickK . . . The question is about extracting the middle value.  You should accept this answer and ask another question, if you do not know how to apply this function to an `update` statement.

Comment: can u plz let me know is there is anyway to parse data like (Technology|Microsoft Technologies|.NET)

Comment: @Karthick K What is the problem you are facing to parse that data

Comment: It has (.Net) at the end...So its not parsing in the way i needed.

Answer (score 2):

Databases are not famous for their ability to parse strings.  Some databases have better functionality than others.  For instance, in MySQL, you could do:

```
select substring_index(place, '|', 1) as place1,
       substring_index(substring_index(place, '|', 2), '|', -1) as place2,
       substring_index(substring_index(place, '|', 3), '|', -1) as place3
```

However, other databases don't support `substring_index()`, although some have similar functions.

Comment: Thank u for ur Response ..but am using Sql Server ,so its not supporting and also i will always have the same structure

Comment: Alas, the question was tagged sql-server long *after* this answer was posted.